# Много doGet запросов в одном сервлете

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Как прописать конкретный путь над методом doGet/doPost, чтобы была возможность иметь их несколько в одном сервлете?

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Для каждого `url` должен быть свой `сервлет`. Эту возможность можно реализовать с помощью `Spring-web`.

Comment: нет, я имею в виду, что мне нужно в одном классе, который extends HttpServle, прописать много методов doGet doPost, каждый из которых относился бы к разному url

Comment: вы не сможете так сделать. Так как элементарно будете нарушать принцип `полиморфизма`). Нельзя переопределить несколько раз метод в одном классе. Вы сможете это реализовать если для каждого `URL` создадите свой сервлет.

Comment: то есть единственный вариант - это создавать большое количество классов-сервлетов?

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняла

Answer (score 0):

Несколько doGet или doPost методов в одном сервлете нельзя переопределить.
Но зато можно выкрутиться так:
в одном doGet() методе можно сделать несколько if else блоков, каждый из которых отрабатывает при определенном значении параметра action(action-это имя параметра, оно может быть любым), который передается в url-e в метод doGet get-запросом. Например какая-то **КНОПКА** на html-странице имеет ссылку на сервлет(***servlet_name***) и параметр action=*update*:
(action-имя параметра, update- значение этого параметра)

```
<a href='/путь к проекту/servlet_name?action=update'>КНОПКА</a>"
```

Тогда в сервлете метод doGet:

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
         String action = req.getParameter("action");
            if (action != null) {
                if (action.equals("delete")) {
    //нужная логика...
    }else if(action.equals("update"){
    // нужная логика 2...
    }
}
```

}
получается один doGet метод может работать с одного рода url, имеющими разные значения параметра action
Для doPost похожая схема:
Можно в одну html форму включить

```
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="form1"/>,
```

в другую

```
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="form2"/>
```

разным value для разных форм. А в методе doPost делать такую-же проверку

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
   String parameter = req.getParameter("form");
         if (parameter.equals("form1")){
               some code...
         }else if (parameter.equals("form2"){
               some code 2...
   }
}
```